# Why doesn't my view display in Landscape instead of Portrait mode?

Tags: iphone, storyboard, screen-orientation

I use to define my UIViews programmatically, setting the orientation via code. I haven't touched Interface Builder in a while and I've decided to go for the new Storyboarding system.

I was pretty happy until I found out that although I have set, in the inspector pane, the appropriate view controller to "Landscape", it never displays in another mode than portrait.

I commented in and out the code in my custom view controller:

```
 - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscape);
}
```

Nothing changes.

My View Controller is itself "under" a Navigation Controller on the Storyboard, so I suspect interference, and it's only the second view in the flow, so the fact that the application itself is defined as portrait should not interfere.

I am looking for ideas to test for at this point, since the application is stripped to so little code I really can't begin to guess where to look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What supported orientations have you specified in Info.plist? In order for a `UINavigationController` to support rotation, all of it's child view controllers must also support rotation to the same orientation.

Comment: Ah.. I missed that. Well, then it's working as intended, even though I'm not exactly happy about it. I'll use a work around by setting the view inside my view 90° right...